# Put HTML input tag cursor on left side of placeholder text

Tags: html, css

When I click on the input, the placeholder text stays (which I want it to do), but the cursor that appears is currently blinking on top of the text, right in the center, and I'd like it to blink directly to the left of the text. I want to keep the placeholder text centered. How can I do this?

Here is my field:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter your email...">
```

Here is all my CSS:

```
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-image-outset:0px;
border-image-repeat:stretch;
border-image-slice:100%;
border-image-source:none;
border-image-width:1;
border-left-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width:1px;
border-right-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width:1px;
border-top-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:1px;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
cursor:text;
display:inline-block;
font-family:azo-sans-web, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
font-stretch:100%;
font-style:normal;
font-variant-caps:normal;
font-variant-east-asian:normal;
font-variant-ligatures:normal;
font-variant-numeric:normal;
font-weight:400;
height:72px;
letter-spacing:0.56px;
line-height:22.8571px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
outline-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
outline-style:none;
outline-width:0px;
padding-bottom:24px;
padding-left:24px;
padding-right:24px;
padding-top:24px;
text-align:center;
text-indent:0px;
text-rendering:auto;
text-shadow:none;
text-transform:none;
width:702px;
word-spacing:0px;
writing-mode:horizontal-tb;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-webkit-box-direction:normal;
-webkit-rtl-ordering:logical;
-webkit-border-image:none;
```

Comment: That's exactly what it does for me in Firefox and Chrome. What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: @JCollier are you also using Firefox, and do you have css on the input field?

Comment: @JCollier check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qz1e2yhf/  (Is the javascript tag necessary??)

Comment: @Pointy I think what I'm asking is clear. I want to cursor to be to the left of the text, not in the center.

Comment: @Rachel_Gallen I'm using Chrome.  And I'll edit the post to put the CSS in.

Comment: Your problem is `text-align: center` then.

Answer (score 2):

What is likely occurring is text-align center is being applied to the input. Be sure the text-align is set to left or not at all for default to the left.

Updated code per comment:

> I want my input to be the same as the first one in your code snippet,
>   with the only difference being the cursor is to the left of the
>   centered text

Only way to do this with pure CSS is to mimic placeholder with another element. This has the side effect though of hiding the placeholder when the input receives focus.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
}
#first-input {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
}
#first-input:focus + .placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input id="first-input" type="text"/>
  <div class="placeholder">Type something..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want my input to be the same as the first one in your code snippet, with the only difference being the cursor is to the left of the centered text. I don't want the placeholder text to be left-aligned, too, like in the second one.